# How to add SMP and Preempt in Kernel module version magic?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to build my custom kernel module. it is compling successfully but while inserting module it is giving me error

```
insmod: init_module 'helloworld.ko' failed (Exec format error)
```

And dmesg Log shows:

```
version magic '3.10.0+ mod_unload ARMv7 p2v8 ' should be '3.10.0 SMP preempt mod_unload ARMv7 p2v8 '
```

How can I add "SMP" & "preempt" in version magic ?

Comment: *"I am trying to build my custom kernel module"* -- Then you may not be building it correctly (i.e. your host build environment references a kernel that is quite different  from the one used for booting on the target).  Your module should automatically inherit the “magic version” of that kernel.  Or are you neglecting to provide the full details of what you are doing?  IOW you probably need to build a kernel with CONFIG_SMP and CONFIG_PREEMPT enabled, although you would still need to deal with the `+` in the version number.

Comment: You could force the version magic to be almost anything you want, but that could be ill-advised with "SMP" and "preempt" differences for a module more complicated than a helloworld.

Comment: Could you supply more details about how you are building the module, such as the commands you are typing and copies of any Makefile or Kbuild file you are using?

Answer (score 3):

Check whether `CONFIG_PREEMPT` and `CONFIG_SMP` is enabled in the kernel config of the kernel which you are using to compile your kernel module. Enable it in your kernel and then recompile your module using this config.

Comment: Thank you. It solved my issue. CONFIG_PREEMPT  & CONFIG_SMP were not enabled in my kernel config.